# PowerShell script to block AD users that didn't log in for 90+days

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I need the users to be blocked after 90+ days of inactivity and I came up with the following code:

```
$main_date = [DateTime]::Today.AddDays(-90)
$DisabledUsers = (get-aduser -filter {(PasswordLastSet -lt $main_date) -and (enabled -eq $true) -and (passwordneverexpires -eq $False) -and (whencreated -le $main_date) -or (LastLogonTimestamp -lt $main_date) -and (passwordneverexpires -eq $False) -and (enabled -eq $True) -and (whencreated -le $main_date)}) | Select-Object samaccountname,Name,@{N ="LastLogonDate";E={if(({$_.lastlogondate -like '*1/1/1601*' -or $_.lastlogondate -eq $null})){'NeverLoggedIn'} Else{({$_.lastlogondate}).tostring("MM/dd/yyyy")}}}
echo $DisabledUsers


ForEach ($DisabledUser in $DisabledUsers) {
    Disable-ADAccount $DisabledUser
}
```

On running this code, I get the following error:

> Disable-ADAccount : Cannot bind parameter 'Identity'. Cannot create object of type "Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADAccount". The adapter cannot set the value of property "Name".

I suppose the output of my main function is somehow not of the proper format and `Disable-ADAccount` doesn't "like" it. However, `echo $DisabledUsers` shows correct users.

I need 2 of the following main checks to be conducted:

- passwordlastset attribute must be less then 90 days
- LastLogonTimestamp attribute must be less then 90 days

Also, I need these additional checks:

- account must be enabled
- password never expires property must be not set
- lastlogondate property must be not empty
- lastlogondate property must not be set to 1/1/1601
- account must be created not earlier than 90 days

Comment: Your `Select-Object` statement ruining your code here, you need to pass in these objects as they're to `Disable-ADAccount`. You can construct your output after that

Comment: I tried, but if I put into my objects `lastlogondate -notlike '*1/1/1601*'` - it doesn't work. It shows - no accounts.

Comment: Try `Disable-ADAccount $DisabledUser.samaccountname`

Comment: To clarify the previous comments, your `Select` is changing the object type from the default AD query result type. `Disable-ADAccount` will probably work just fine on $DisabledUsers if you leave out the  `|Select-Object samaccountname...` after the query. To see what you've got after creating $DisabledUsers without the `Select`, do that separately: `$DisabledUsers | Select-Object samaccountname [...] | FT`. Then run the disable: `Foreach ($DisabledUser in $DisabledUsers)  {Disable-AdAccount $DisabledUser}`. To test just one in $DisabledUsers, do `Disable-AdAccount $DisabledUsers[0]`

Comment: @GabrielLuci this actually works, but the filters are not working. I want the script to make no actions on accounts with empty lastlogondate and if lastlogondate is set to 1/1/1601

Comment: @Link You can add an [`If`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-if?view=powershell-7.3) inside the loop to check that.

Comment: Can you help me with main function? If I use `$DisabledUsers = (get-aduser -filter {lastlogondate -notlike "*1/1/1601*"})` it show's - no such users

Comment: @GabrielLuci nvm. I understood and made what you suggest (if inside the loop). I'll update my code later. For now, trying to convert time to NT time format to actually test if loop is working.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I came up with this code. I removed the `passwordlastset` check, because I have a user who has the `password never expires` attribute set and his `password last set` is much longer than 90 days.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$main_date = [DateTime]::Today.AddDays(-90)
$LogDate = get-date -f yyyy_MM_dd_hh_mm
$DisabledUsers = (get-aduser -searchbase "OU=IT-Dep,OU=AllUsers,DC=Enterprise,DC=local" -Properties LastlogonDate,whencreated -filter {(LastLogonTimestamp -lt $main_date) -and (enabled -eq $True) -and (whencreated -le $main_date)} | Select-Object name,samaccountname,@{N="LastLogonDate";E={if ($_.lastlogondate -like '*1/1/1601*' -or $_.lastlogondate -eq $null){'NeverLoggedIn'}else{$_.lastlogondate}}})
echo $DisabledUsers

#Create an empty array for the log file
$LogArray = @()

#Checking if $DisabledUsers is not empty
if (-not ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($DisabledUsers)))
{
    ForEach ($DisabledUser in $DisabledUsers) 
    {
        if ($DisabledUser.LastLogonDate -notlike 'NeverLoggedIn')
        {
            #Sets the user objects description attribute to a date stamp. Example "11/13/2011"
            $DateOfDisable = (get-date -f yyyy_MM_dd_hh:mm)
            set-aduser -identity $DisabledUser.samaccountname -Description "Account disabled on $DateOfDisable due to inactivity for 90 days"

            #Actually, disabling accounts
            Disable-ADAccount $DisabledUser.samaccountname
    
            #Create new object for logging
            $obj = New-Object PSObject
            $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Name" -Value $DisabledUser.Name
            $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "samAccountName" -Value $DisabledUser.samaccountname
            $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Status" -Value 'Disabled'

            #Adds object to the log array
            $LogArray += $obj
        }
    }
        
    #Exports log array to CSV file in the temp directory with a date and time stamp in the file name.
    $logArray | Export-Csv "C:\Temp\Report_of_disabled_users_$logDate.csv" -Encoding UTF8
        
    #Send e-mail to Global Helpdesk with report generated
    $emailFrom = "noc@enterprise.com.ua"
    $emailTo = "noc@enterprise.com.ua"
    $subject = "Disabled users due to inactivity for 90 days"
    $list = ($LogArray | Out-String)
    $body = "These accounts were disabled on $DateOfDisable due to inactivity for 90 days `n $list"
    $smtpServer = "mail.bank-bs.local"
    $attachment = "C:\Temp\Report_of_disabled_users_$logDate.csv"

    Send-MailMessage -To $emailTo -From $emailFrom -Subject $subject -body $body -SmtpServer $smtpServer -attachment $attachment -Encoding utf8

    #removing temp file, so the place will be clean
    Remove-Item "C:\Temp\Report_of_disabled_users_$logDate.csv"
}
else     
{
    Write-Output "No disabled users to process for $main_date"
}
```